# FreeGLUT compiled dll + lib?

Tags: opengl, dll, freeglut

I'm trying to get FreeGLUT working. For a reason I don't get, no binaries are distributed. Where can I download the .lib and the .dll files?

Comment: It's a lot easier for library developers to provide the sources and allow you to compile it, than to provide precompiled binaries for every OS/compiler in existence. That being said, compiling it is fairly trivial. So perhaps tell us what it is you're using (which compiler. OS is Windows it seems) and where you're stuck.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and Windows. I tried compiling it but there were include errors (it think because of the <gl/...>). Also types like `GLint` are used which can't be found.

Comment: Please update the question to include the exact version of FreeGLUT you're compiling and the exact errors you get. I don't have VS2012 here at the moment, but I hardly think it's a version specific issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download them at [FreeGLut download page](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download), in section **Prepackaged Releases**

[Direct Link](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/)

Please note it's community-maintained. Library authors only do provide source code.

**Citation from the page itself:**
*If you have problems with these packages, please contact their maintainers - we of the freeglut team probably can't help.*

If you provide the compilation/linking logs from your attempts with source distribution, we could find a reason for it not working as well.

Comment: Ha, can't believe I overlooked that. +1 Though building it yourself should really be no problem at all either.

Comment: The direct link is dead...

Comment: @JanM. Not for me right now.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz they must have fixed it since April 2016 :P