# Cannot #include freeglut of OpenGL in Visual Studio C++ 2013

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I want to begin programming with C++ OpenGl, and thus have downloaded `freeglut` to be included in my programn.

I have defined statically `FREEGLUT_STATIC`

Here is my source.cpp:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\GLU.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>

#include "Source.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

source.h

```
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
```

But it does not work, the error is:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'freeglut.lib'
```

It's worth mentioning that I have added the libraries directories to the project, and even when I type `Gl/` visual studio 2013 automatically suggest the libraries and headers which means it knows the directory,

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300059/freeglut-compiled-dll-lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. I should simlpy do the following:

Right click on my project in Visual Studio, go to the properties, and then to VC++ Directories, click on "Library Directories" and then add a new path:

under the freeglut main directory in your hard drive, there is a folder called lib/x86/Debug, just add the full path and then apply that.

Your script should be executed properly.

Answer (score 1):

The include works alright (otherwise you'd get an error at compile time, not at link time). The library file itself (`freeglut.lib`) seems to be missing. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300059/freeglut-compiled-dll-lib) addreses your problem.

EDIT: Updated my answer because obviously just the binary for the lib is missing. Same link already given in a comment by swaldi.

Comment: it is a file "freeglut.lib" ? There is no such thing in my freeglut folder.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You already have it in your linker settings, otherwise the linker wouldn't know what to look for. Seems you are not the first to have this problem. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300059/freeglut-compiled-dll-lib.